# String replace, remove fastest way

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, html-agility-pack

I'm reading with html agility pack a forum message into a string (~120 words).

From this string i want to remove the quote (~30 words). The quote is also available as string and it always stands at the beginning of the message.

So what do you think will be the fastest way to achive this?
(before this substraction, i already cleanup the strings from special characters using regex to replace e.g. " with ""\")

As far as i can see i have various options: string.replace, stringbuilder.replace, regex.replace? What about counting the words (length of quote is known ) and remove them from original string?

Any comment is welcome :-)

Thanks, 
 Ralf

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to instrument the various ways using something like the Stopwatch class. If you already know where the start and end of the string to be removed is, I'm guessing that a simple string.Substring() call would be hard to beat.

Comment: Hi Matthew,You are right.. even i did not measure, using substring should be the fastest. I will go this way. Thanks.

Comment: The fastest would be to turn the string into an array of chars and do the processing yourself into another array of chars. That said, with such small data-sets, the hit of what you are describing will be so neglible that you probably won't even be able to see it with a sampling debugger.